# Azure - What causes a ServiceBus Topic to be "partitioned"

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-bicep

So I have a bicep file that is iterating over an array of 200+ strings, and is supposed to create a correlation filter for each string.

```
var strings = [ "xxx", "yyyy" ... ]

resource CorrelationFilters 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics/subscriptions/rules@2021-06-01-preview' = [for code in strings: {
  name: '${code}Filter' 
  parent: parentName
  properties: {
    filterType: 'CorrelationFilter'
    correlationFilter: {
      properties: {
        subscription: code
      }
    }
  }
}]
```

However, it is only creating a correlation filter for the first 100 elements in the array.  As far as I can tell there isn't anything wrong with the bicep/code itself.

So i did some research, and see this in the Azure documentation:
[image]

So my question is, does creating a CorrelationFilter on a topic cause it become "partitioned"?  It makes sense logically, but I can't seem to find anything that indicates it does, and ChatGpt seems to think that correlation filters do not cause it to be partitioned.  I'd just like to confirm if this is the culprit of the missing correlation filters or not.

Comment: `ChatGpt seems to think that correlation filters do not cause it to be partitioned.` - That is correct. When you create a Topic (or Queue), at that time you decide whether that entity will be partitioned.

Comment: I am wondering if you are only fetching just the 1st 100 filters or the tool you are using to see the filters is fetching just the 1st 100 filters and not all.

Comment: I'm also now wondering if this might be the case.  the Azure Portal does not seem to display filters beyond 100

Comment: Try using Service Bus Explorer or some code to list the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, my question is, does creating a Correlation Filter on a topic causes it to become "partitioned"?

After exploring on this, I found that`Correlation filter` on a topic doesn't cause any partitioning on the topics.
Here partitioning relates to the division of a topic into smaller units for operations and performance. Correlation filters would not trigger any partitioning behavior.

Reference: [Blog](https://www.pulumi.com/ai/answers/a9NNJbceroysgthqB9XfMP/applying-azure-service-bus-correlation-filters)

*Missing filters issue might be due to following reasons:*

Few deployment tools like bicep in Azure might have limitations on the number of resources created in a single deployment.

To check this, create an array of small string length (Eg: 20 at a time) and deploy it. If you are able to view all the filters, then it must be a limitation with bicep.

I tried to add the correlation filters on the service bus subscriptions for a small amount of string data and it was successful as shown.

```bash
var strings = [ 'xxx', 'yyyy', 'zzzz']
param NamespaceName string = 'servjs'
param TopicName string = 'latestjt'
param subsc string = 'subscja'
param location string = resourceGroup().location
resource serviceBus 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces@2022-10-01-preview' = {
  name: NamespaceName
  location: location
  properties: {
  }
}

resource serviceBusTopic 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics@2022-01-01-preview' = {
  parent: serviceBus
  name: TopicName
  properties: {

  }
}
resource sub 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics/subscriptions@2022-10-01-preview' = {
  name: subsc
  properties: {}
  parent: serviceBusTopic
}
resource CorrelationFilters 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics/subscriptions/rules@2021-06-01-preview' = [for code in strings: {
  name: '${code}Filter' 
  parent: sub
  properties: {
    filterType: 'CorrelationFilter'
    correlationFilter: {
      properties: {
        subscription: code
      }
    }
  }
}]
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

[image]